# scheduled tasks group multithread execution in java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I need to emulate behaviour of some clients what send requests to the Kafka.

One client start the session and send different requests with different schedule. (A-type of request sends every 10 seconds, B-type of reques sends every 5 seconds, etc)

So, I need to implement some multithread executor, there each thread will execute some different requests with the different schedule during the time.

Can some one help me with the idea which instrument of Java concurrent can be applied here?

Or maybe I want to implement one big scheduler-pool that will store tasks for all clients and will provide task and task context to the free thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Executors framework makes scheduling a repeating task quite easy.

Define your task as a `Runnable` or `Callable`.

Specify an initial delay, and how often to repeat.

```
ScheduledExecutorService ses = Executors. newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor() ;
ses.scheduleAtFixedRate( myRunnable , 1 , 10 , TimeUnit.SECONDS ) ;
ses.scheduleAtFixedRate( myOtherRunnable , 3 , 5 , TimeUnit.SECONDS ) ;
```

Be sure to shutdown the executor service. Otherwise, the backing thread pool may continue running like a zombie ‍♂️.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use **java.util.Timer** to handle your jobs !

example :

```
public static void main(String [] args)
{
        Timer timer = new Timer();

        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("SEND A-TYPE REQUEST");
            }
        } , 0 , 10000);// 0ms first execution delay and 10000ms period

        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("SEND B-TYPE REQUEST");
            }
        } , 0 , 5000); // 0ms first execution delay and 5000ms period

}
```

This tasks all running in same thread so if you have high compute task or if task waiting for something after running like read or write files create 2 difference timer for difference type of requests.

Also first argument of **time.schedule()** is an instance of **TimerTask** object that you can easily extends it to create custom tasks and supply needed values to it.

***EDIT :***

As mentioned in comments you can do it with executor services too.

example :

```
public static void main(String [] args)
{
        java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService =
                java.util.concurrent.Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1); // pool thread size


        scheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(
                new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        System.out.println("SEND A-TYPE REQUEST");
                    }
                }
                , 0 , 10 , TimeUnit.SECONDS); // 0s first execution delay and 10s period

        scheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(
                new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        System.out.println("SEND B-TYPE REQUEST");
                    }
                }
                , 0 , 5 , TimeUnit.SECONDS); // 0s first execution delay and 5s period

}
```

If you set pool size one so all tasks run in same thread also if you set the pool size with more than 1 your tasks run on difference threads but never same task run parallel !

Task passed as **Runnable** or **Callable** to executor services.

But you have to know both way will handle your job and there is no difference for you. Maybe sometimes better to implement your own thread to handle this type of jobs.([Related Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53992215/using-a-scheduledexecutorservice-to-run-a-task-on-a-periodic-basis-in-java/53992463#53992463))

Comment: The Executors framework added to modern Java supplants the use of `Timer`.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for the reply. So, if I need, for example, 100 instances of running repeatable  task groups: 1 group (task a, task b), 2 group (task a, task b) etc. Roughly speaking, I need only submit a 100 * 2 of repeatable tasks by scheduleAtFixedRate?

Comment: @Tomas0808 yes. But if your tasks block thread or need long time to execute maybe using just one Thread cause problems and if you wana just produce to Kafka Topics it is good to use just one Thread for all tasks .